# adaptar logo al tamaño del inpút angular

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, scss

hola buenas queria hacer una consulta un poco basica de angular para que intento adaptar un logo a un input pero no se que esta pasando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si notan el logo no es acorde al tamaño y me gustaria que se viera acorde al tamaño.

este es mi codigo

```
<div class="jumbtron">
  <h1 class="display-4 text-center">Targetas de Credito</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <h6 class="text-center">
        Agregar Targeta
      </h6>
      <app-targeta-credito></app-targeta-credito>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <h6 class="text-center">
        Listado de Targetas
      </h6>
      <app-list-targeta-credito></app-list-targeta-credito>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

este es mi codigo de app targeta credito

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text bg-white">
          <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Titular">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <div class="input-group-text bg-white">
          <i class="fas fa-credit-card"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero de Targeta">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-7">

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text bg-white">
              <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text bg-white">
              <i class="fas fa-key"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="CVV">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-grup">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Aceptar</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

pero como notaran aquí se vuelve a poner chueco, entonces nose como hacer que los iconos tengan el mismo tamaño del input, aparte de que como notaran el tema del espaciado no está bien, igualmente parece como si no reconociera que el botón quiero que tenga el tamaño total del contenedor donde esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

deberia quedarme asi jeje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece que el código importante está dentro de app-targeta-credito, por lo que edita tu publicación y agrega aquel código

Comment: @Yussef, gracias ya lo edité